# Is having multiple authentication providers at the same time possible in ASP.NET MVC3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, httpwebrequest, asp.net-membership, authorization

A client application is uploading an audio file in "chunks" to an MVC3 site. A client uses `HttpWebRequest` `POST` to do it.

On the server, I have the following controller action:

```
  [Authorize]
  [HttpPost]
  public JsonResult RecieveChunk(string id, [ModelBinder(typeof(AudioChunkModelBinder))] byte[] audio)
        {
            //Process chunk

            var chunk = new AudioChunk
            {
                ThoughtId = Guid.Parse(id),
                Data = audio
            };

            //Process chunk by BL

            return new JsonResult {Data = "Success"};
        }
```

Currently, a built-in `AspNetMemebershipProvider` is handling the authorization, so the client app has to first authenticate at the logon page, obtain cookie into a `CookieContainer` and then make a call to a server to upload a chunk of data.

I want to allow clients to also be able to anonymously upload audio files to the server, without a need to previously register. They the client app code will provide the same guid each time the file is uploaded from the same device.

I want both categories of users to share the same `RecieveChunk` action to do it. But they must be authrized either anonymously (with just `guid`), or with the logon/pass combination.

Can I have two different controllers linked to two different authentication providers? The third controller, that has `[Authorize]` marked action, will allow action if either one provider has given a user a cookie (or some other auth method).

Is it possible in general in ASP.NET MVC3?

Comment: From what you say here, your upload action does *not* require Authorization, and so should not have that attribute. Instead, you should use code in the Action to determine if they are logged in or not, and act accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing. So I am assuming the answer is just - No, only one implementation of Membership provider acts at the same time application-wide?

Comment: Umm, no; that's not what you are doing. You have the Authorize attribute there. Also, anonymous users are, by definition, *not authenticated*. So what you are looking for is *not* multiple Membership Providers.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, sorry, my English resulted in a confusion. I meant that before I've read your initial comment, I went ahead, and did what you mentioned - started to treat an anonymous users as not authenticated, removing the [Authorize].

Comment: ahh, ok! And yes; two Membership Providers is not directly supported. You could certainly implement your own system with it's own Action Filters instead of Authorize.

Comment: Oh, correct! I am just learning ASP.NET MVC, so all the functionality implementation approaches are not yet obvious to me. You should post the "Custom Action Filer" approach to my problem as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments you can create a custom implementation of the [`FilterAttribute` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filterattribute.aspx)  and implement the [`IAuthorizationFilter` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iauthorizationfilter.aspx).  For example here is the `ChildActionOnlyAttribute` implementation:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class ChildActionOnlyAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
  public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
  {
    if (filterContext == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
    if (!filterContext.IsChildAction)
      throw Error.ChildActionOnlyAttribute_MustBeInChildRequest(filterContext.ActionDescriptor);
  }
}
```

And here is the `RequireHttpsAttribute` implementation:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class RequireHttpsAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
  public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
  {
    if (filterContext == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection)
      return;
    this.HandleNonHttpsRequest(filterContext);
  }

  protected virtual void HandleNonHttpsRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
  {
    if (!string.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.RequireHttpsAttribute_MustUseSsl);
    string url = "https://" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
    filterContext.Result = (ActionResult) new RedirectResult(url);
  }
}
```

So you could do something like:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
  public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
  {
    if (filterContext == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");

    var guidPresent = CheckForGuid();

    if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && !guidPresent)
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Must authenticate properly")
  }
}
```